# Rewrite htaccess without file name

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to have a rewriterule for these addresses , I checked over internet and couldn't find something that suits this . 
so I need "http://www.xxx.com/ecommerce/automated/?city=london"

to convert to "http://www.xxx.com/ecommerce/automated/London/"

Comment: What have you tried? It's simple (if the factual directory setup was known). Use `\w+` for matching words e.g. Can you list some examples which you found but didn't work?

Comment: The very same thing like this other friend "Jonathan" listed below this.

Comment: You could have told that before. Redundant answers are a common result if you leave out research details. Use the edit button, provide more information besides that you "tried something, and something else doesn't work". Directory setup was asked for, current .htaccess is another prerequisite.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)/ index.php?city=$1
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?city=$1
```

It assumes you're using a URL like:

`http://www.xxx.com/ecommerce/automated/index.php?city=london`

Note the addition of "index.php" to your original URL.